# Plotting the explained variance ratio from PCA

Tags: python, matplotlib, pca, eigenvalue, dimensionality-reduction

I'm having trouble plotting my explained variance ratio in PCA. I'm building PCA from scratch and the plotting results is difference than using PCA from sklearn. My code is below :

```
class PCA:
def __init__ (self, n_components):
    self.n_components = n_components
    
def fit(self, X):
    self.x_mean = np.mean(X , axis = 0)
    X_meaned = X - self.x_mean
    cov_mat = np.cov(X_meaned.T)
    eigen_values , eigen_vectors = np.linalg.eigh(cov_mat)
    sorted_index = np.argsort(eigen_values)[::-1]
    self.eigen_values = eigen_values[sorted_index].real
    self.eigen_vectors = eigen_vectors[:,sorted_index].real
    
def transform(self, x):
    x_new = x - self.x_mean
    return np.matmul(x_new, self.eigen_vectors[:,:self.n_components])

def fit_transform (self,X):
    self.fit(X)
    return self.transform(X)

def plot(self):
    exp_var = self.eigen_values/sum(self.eigen_values)
    cum_var = np.cumsum(exp_var)
    plt.figure(1, figsize=(6,4))
    plt.clf()
    plt.plot(cum_var, linewidth= 3)
    plt.axis('tight')
    plt.grid()
    plt.xlabel("No of Components")
    plt.ylabel("Cumulative Variance")
    plt.show()
```

The result for the plot is
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymzBT.png)

Meanwhile the plot generated using PCA from sklearn is [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNtiy.png)

I know that explained_variance stands for the eigen_values/sum(eigen_values), but why does the plot did not getting the same result?

Comment: Notice the x-axes on both plots are different.

Comment: Could you explain what the problem is? The plots are, except for the x-axis, exactly the same and seem to reach +-1.0 at x=170.

Comment: i want to generate a plot exactly like the plot generated from PCA library. I'm building the PCA from scratch and the plot result is different

Comment: using PCA from sklearn, i able to generate the plot using this : var = pca.explained_variance_/np.sum(pca.explained_variance_)
cum_var = np.cumsum(var). what is the equivalen for explained_variance_ function?